# Initialization error in eclipse for cucumber test

Tags: eclipse, cucumber

When i run the JUnit test in Eclipse for Cucumber (feature file added no error in that) getting the below error.

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:  gherkin/IGherkinDialectProvider at 
>   cucumber.runtime.RuntimeOptionsFactory.create(RuntimeOptionsFactory.java:25)
>   at  cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.(Cucumber.java:74)

Comment: Maybe you are missing [Gherkin](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/gherkin).

Comment: Can you add the POM? Or a list of the jars if u are not using maven

Comment: Have you solved your problem?